# Database connection sometimes lost in AWS

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel project hosted in AWS. Sometimes I have this kind of error (I have hidden a part of the hostname)

> 05/11/2019 11:47:16[05-Nov-2019 10:47:16] WARNING: [pool www] child 3752 said into stderr: "[2019-11-05 11:47:16] prod.ERROR: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not translate host name "cahrh******.ckbo*****.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com" to address: Try again (SQL: select * from "members" where "id" = C2eccaee**********4c2b164c3ce1 and "members"."deleted_at" is null limit 1)

Clearly it means a temporary network issue. I wonder if there is some options in Laravel (.env or config or other) to declare "retry automatically if there is this kind of error".

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: it's a dns resolution issue, nothing related to any laravel code. Contact your provider.

Comment: Hi N69S. Thanks for your quick reply. Yes I know it is a dns issue. But I wondered if there was something possible to retry this request automatically.

Comment: try posting your question on https://serverfault.com/ since it is about general server issues